# Select objects from file A where value of path appear in file B in jq

Tags: json, jq

I want to filter with jq the objects from json content of this `fileA`

```json
[
  {
    "id": "bird",
    "content": {
        "key1": "a"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "dog",
    "content": {
        "key1": "b"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "cat",
    "content": {
        "key1": "c"
    }
  }
]
```

Where the id appear in this json content of `fileB` called `theId` (the sort order has no importance) :

```json
[
  {
    "theId": "cat"
  },
  {
    "theId": "bird"
  }
]
```

Expected result (the sort order has no importance) :

```json
[
  {
    "id": "cat",
    "content": {
      "key1": "c"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "bird",
    "content": {
      "key1": "a"
    }
  }
]
```

I think I can do this in a bash loop :

1. looping on ids from fileB
2. execute jq to extract the given id such as

> ```
> jq -c "map(select(.id | contains(\"$id\")))"
> ```

but I have to separate them with **`,`** which seems dirty.

I don't know how to say to jq `the filter is composed of values of the given array which is stored in fileB`

Is it possible ?

Comment: Can you please fix the JSON values

Comment: JSON values fixed in the output, sorry.

Comment: Your output is invalid JSON, it has duplicate keys

Comment: You're right, fixed by addind missing braces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
$ jq 'map(.theId) as $ids | input | map(select(.id | IN($ids[])))' fileB fileA
[
  {
    "id": "bird",
    "content": {
      "key1": "a"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "cat",
    "content": {
      "key1": "c"
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution using [`--slurpfile`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Invokingjq):

```
jq --slurpfile b fileB 'map(select(.id|IN($b[][].theId)))' fileA
```

Comment: Thank you, it works fine !
I don't understand this part `$b[][]` : what does the double `[]` mean  ?

Comment: @BJam `$b` is read with `--slurpfile` and will contain an array. The `.[]` filter streams the elements of an array or the values of an object. So a (simplified) fileB with content `[{"theId": "cat"}]` would be read as `[[{"theId": "cat"}]]` (this is `$b`). `$b[]` produces `[{"theId": "cat"}]`, and `$b[][]` produces `{"theId": "cat"}` (a stream with a single object). Filters are applied to all elements of a stream. `IN` expects a stream for its first argument. `$b[][]` could also be written as `$b[] | .[]` or `$b | .[] | .[]`.